# Using $POST Variables with Spaces

Tags: php, html, post, syntax, whitespace

I am using a PHP page to construct an email.  Part of the email text is provided by $POST variables from an ealier page.  Some of the variables contain spaces, which is causing the strings to truncate to a single word in my email.  Any syntax ideas on how to get the whole string into the text of my email?  ' . $_POST['VariableName'] . ' is obviously not working.

```
$message = '
<html>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>EuroClassic Transfer Notice</title>
</HEAD>

<body bgcolor="#F5EEDB">

<TABLE ID=hor-minimalist-b SUMMARY=EuroClassic Customer>
<THEAD>
<TR>
<TH colspan=4 scope=col>Shipping Logistics:</th>
</TR>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>

<TR>
<TD>Shipping From: </TD>
<TD><INPUT type=text size=35 name=from value=' . $_POST['from'] . '></TD>
<TD>Shipping To: </TD>
<TD><INPUT type=text size=35 name=ToLocation value=' . $_POST['ToLocation'] . '></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>PO Number: </TD>
<TD><INPUT type=text size=20 name=PO value=' . $_POST['PO'] . '></TD>
<TD>Address: </TD>
<TD><INPUT type=text size=35 name=address value=' . $_POST['address'] . '></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ship Date: </TD>
<TD><INPUT type=text size=20 name=ShipDate value=' . $_POST['ShipDate'] . '></TD>
<TD>City/State/ZIP: </TD>
<TD><INPUT type=text size=35 name=city value=' . $_POST['city'] . '></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Arrival Date: </TD>
<TD><INPUT type=text size=20 name=ArrivalDate value=' . $_POST['ArrivalDate'] . '></TD>
<TD>Freight: </TD>
<TD><INPUT type=text size=20 name=cost value=' . $_POST['cost'] . '></TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>

</div>
</body>
</html>
';
```

Comment: Also read up on HEREDOC string syntax for cases like that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just put quotes around the attribute values.

Comment: like instead of: `<INPUT type=text size=35 name=from value=' . $_POST['from'] . '>` type `<INPUT type="text" size="35" name="from" value="' . $_POST['from'] . '">`. And always quote attributes - html standard requires this.

Comment: in addition, use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` to escape the data.

Comment: Not only that, but you may need to strip escape slashes or escape quotes too.  Just keep it in mind.

Comment: @Sterve you should accept some answers, starting with this one.